# error after installing xcode 5: value for key (UIHighlighted) is not a boolean

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

After installing xcode 5 and running the simulator I get following error:

'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeBoolForKey:]: value for key (UIHighlighted) is not a boolean'

The app closes just before opening. It was working fine on xcode 4.6. What could it be?

It seems to be related with a UIImageView, is that the case?

Comment: what are you trying to unarchive?  is UIHighlighted a key that you know about?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set for exceptions? What is the offending line of code?

Comment: It was a UIImageView, that had the highlighted property set. The answer of alpere is correct.

Comment: @user2394901 can you set my answer as correct?

Comment: @alpere, I'am a little noob here, how do you do it?

Comment: @user2394901 Click the checkmark under the post, on the left. It should be right below the arrows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had one UIImageView that has the highlighted property set, which seems like causing the issue.

Unseting the highlighted property of the UIImageView using the Interface Builder solved my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unseting the highlighted property of the UIImageView"? In Interface builder, Highligted checkbox is unchecked, and still having the problem.

Comment: Be sure to check all the UIImageView's if you have more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your deployment Target in xcode. Change it to with latest iOS or last released  iOS version. after that clean the project and build.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @alpere answer, my problem was with a custom UICollectionViewCell where I had added some additional images and labels. I found that I had to also implement the `setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted` method in my custom cell...

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    self.songView.highlighted = highlighted;
    self.songTitle.highlighted = highlighted;
    self.trackStack.highlighted = highlighted;
}
```